# Why does 'return' end a function

Tags: function, return

I'm just curious about why `return` ends the function.
Why do we not write

```
function Foo (){
BAR = calculate();
give back BAR; 

//do sth later
log(BAR);
end; 
}
```

Why do we need to do this?

```
function Foo (){
BAR = calculate(); 
log(BAR);
return BAR;
}
```

Is this to prevent multiple usage of a `give back/return value` in a function?

Comment: Which programming language is that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually that looks like PHP

Comment: What if you wanted to return something different from the function depending upon conditions? How would you do that in your first function?

Comment: @lurker If (condition) { give back value; end; } else {give back otherValue; end;}

Comment: Why do you consider the first way preferred to the second? It seems more verbose and awkward to me. Every language chooses how they want to solve the problem of returning a value from a function.

Comment: @lurker And why does no language implement this approach? This is my question

Comment: How would the control flow work then? Would the caller get to work with the return value while the callee continues doing something in parallel? So this would be implicit multitasking? How would this be coordinated? Threading, asynchronously? What if the function `return`s more than once?

Comment: I think I explained why no language does it that way. I'll rephrase what I said: the approach you show is verbose and a bit awkward with no clear advantage over using `return`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a *function* stems from mathematics, e.g. `x = f(y)`. Once you have computed `f(y)` for a specific value of `y`, you can simply substitute that value in that equation for the same result, e.g. `x = 42`. So the notion of a function having *one result* or *one return value* is quite strong. Further, such mathematical functions are *pure*, meaning they have no *side effects*. In the above formula it doesn’t make a difference whether you write `f(y)` or its computed result `42`, the function doesn’t *do* anything else and hence won’t change the result. Being able to make these assumptions makes it much easier to reason about formulas and programs.

`return` in programming also has practical implementation implications, as most languages typically pop the stack upon returning, based on the assumption/restriction that it’s not needed any further.

Many languages do allow a function to “spit out” a value yet continue, which is usually implemented as generators and the `yield` keyword. However, the generator won’t typically simply continue running in the background, it needs to be explicitly invoked again to yield its next value. A *transfer of control* is necessary; either the generator runs, or its caller does, they can’t both run simultaneously.

If you did want to run two pieces of code simultaneously, be that a generator or a function’s “after `return` block”, you need to decide on a mode of multitasking like threading, or cooperative multitasking (async execution) or something else, which brings with it all the fun difficulties of managing shared resource access and the like. While it’s not unthinkable to write a language which would handle that implicitly and elegantly, elegant implicit multitasking which manages all these difficulties automagically simply does not fit into most C-like languages. Which is likely one of many reasons leading to a simple stack-popping, function-terminating `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using `return` gives you a lot of flexibility regarding where, when and how you return the value of a function as well as an easy to read statement of 'I am now returning this value'.

If following your idea, you could have a situation where the function got evaulated to some value and you have to figure out if that assignment got changed somewhere later in the flow.